# SSL Session reuse performance

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a server using SSL and capable of doing session resumption, but when reusing the session, SSL_read() function takes more time.
The following sequence, shows what is happening:

1. Establish the connection (First handshake ≈ 4 seconds). Here I save the context and the session on the client to be reused.
2. Read the data ≈ 0.01 seconds
3. Close the connection
4. Re-establish the connection with the context and the session previously saved (≈ 0.01 seconds)
5. Read the data ≈ 0.2 seconds
6. Close the connection

So, what would be the reason that step 2) is so much faster than step 5)

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you have a pcap capture then we are sure of these times you are logging within your code ?

Comment: Hi @EugèneAdell, yes, these times come from the server